# помогите разобраться с задачей js

Tags: javascript

*Напиши функцию `makeTask(data)` которая принимает один параметр `data` - объект со следующими свойствами.

`text` - текст задачи. `category` - категория задачи. `priority` - приоритет задачи. Функция должна составить и вернуть новый объект задачи, не изменяя напрямую параметр `data`. В новом объекте должно быть свойство `completed`, значение которого хранится в одноимённой локальной переменной.

В параметре `data` гарантированно будет только свойство `text`, а остальные два, `category` и `priority`, могут отсутствовать. Тогда, в новом объекте задачи, в свойствах `category` и `priority` должны быть значения по умолчанию, хранящиеся в одноимённых локальных переменных.*

тесты

*Объявлена функция `makeTask(data)`.
Вызов `makeTask({})` возвращает `{ category: 'Общее', priority: 'Обычный', completed: false }`.

Вызов `makeTask({ category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор' })` возвращает `{ category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор', completed: false }`.

Вызов `makeTask({ category: 'Финансы', text: 'Забрать проценты' })` возвращает `{ category: 'Финансы', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Забрать проценты', completed: false }`.

Вызов `makeTask({ priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Выбрать шампунь' })` возвращает `{ category: 'Общее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Выбрать шампунь', completed: false }`.

Вызов `makeTask({ text: 'Купить хлеб' })` возвращает `{ category: 'Общее', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Купить хлеб', completed: false }`.*

вот сама функция которую мне нужно дополнить:

```
function makeTask(data) {
  const completed = false;
  const category = 'Общее';
  const priority = 'Обычный';
  // Пиши код ниже этой строки

  // Пиши код выше этой строки
}
```

я пробую решить задачу таким вот образом:

```
let returnData = { ...data }
   
if (text = 'Вынести мусор') {
    returnData = { category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор', completed: false }
}
if (text = 'Забрать проценты') {
   returnData = { category: 'Финансы', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Забрать проценты', completed: false } 
}
        
return returnData;
```

Comment: function makeTask(data) {
    const completed = false;
    const category = 'Общее';
    const priority = 'Обычный';
    // Пиши код ниже этой строки
    
    let returnData = { ...data }
   
    if (text = 'Вынести мусор') {
        returnData = { category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор', completed: false }
    }
    if (text = 'Забрать проценты') {
       returnData = { category: 'Финансы', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Забрать проценты', completed: false } 
    }
        
    

    return returnData; 
  // Пиши код выше этой строки
}
makeTask(data)

Comment: создай сначала объект с дефолтными значениями, а потом туда подставляй значения из аргумента функции data, то есть пришло значение data.category, измени его, не пришло, значит дефолтное останется, и так далее.

Comment: а в автопроверке проходит только одно значение,  а должно быть от двух

Comment: @Jean-Claude а можете на примере, потому что уже совсем жестко туплю ?

Comment: самое интересное в том что, эту задачу дают на обучении и плавно подводят к ней! Из-за невнимательности, к сожалению новичку решить ее сложно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из вариантов (используя [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)):

```js
function makeTask(data) {
  const completed = false;
  const category = 'Общее';
  const priority = 'Обычный';
  // Пиши код ниже этой строки
  return { ...{ category, priority, completed }, ...data };
  // Пиши код выше этой строки
}

console.log(makeTask({}));
// { category: 'Общее', priority: 'Обычный', completed: false }

console.log(makeTask({ category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор' }));
// { category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор', completed: false }

console.log(makeTask({ category: 'Финансы', text: 'Забрать проценты' }));
// { category: 'Финансы', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Забрать проценты', completed: false }

console.log(makeTask({ priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Выбрать шампунь' }));
// { category: 'Общее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Выбрать шампунь', completed: false }

console.log(makeTask({ text: 'Купить хлеб' }));
// { category: 'Общее', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Купить хлеб', completed: false }
```

Comment: супер, блин реально стыдно, что я не додумался! жму руку! гениально простое решение!!!

Answer (score 3):

Если ответы должны быть один в один как примере вашем (completed должен быть последним), то, так например.

```js
function makeTask(data) {
    // console.log('makeTask · data', data);
    const completed = false;
    const category = 'Общее';
    const priority = 'Обычный';

    // Пиши код ниже этой строки
    let res = {
        category,
        priority,
        ...data,
        completed,
    };

    console.log('makeTask · res', res);
    return res;
    // Пиши код выше этой строки
}

makeTask({});
//{ category: 'Общее', priority: 'Обычный', completed: false }.

makeTask({ category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор' });
//{ category: 'Домашнее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Вынести мусор', completed: false }.

makeTask({ category: 'Финансы', text: 'Забрать проценты' });
//{ category: 'Финансы', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Забрать проценты', completed: false }.

makeTask({ priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Выбрать шампунь' });
//{ category: 'Общее', priority: 'Низкий', text: 'Выбрать шампунь', completed: false }.

makeTask({ text: 'Купить хлеб' });
//{ category: 'Общее', priority: 'Обычный', text: 'Купить хлеб', completed: false }.
```

Comment: Но только если не подразумевается, что в аргументе функции пользователь не может задавать `completed`, иначе значение по умолчанию перезапишет пользовательское.